# Apply function to column in Pandas depending on row value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
date,id,value
1/1/2017,5,300
1/1/2017,51,300
1/1/2017,54,300
1/2/2017,5,100
1/2/2017,51,100
1/2/2017,54,100
```

and I have a dictionary mapping `id` to an adjustment factor as such:

```
{5: 20, 51: 23.5, 54:10}
```

I want to `add` the factor corresponding to the `id` to the `value` column in my dataframe, resulting in:

```
date,id,value,adjusted_value
1/1/2017,5,300,300+20=320
1/1/2017,51,310,310+23.5=333.5
1/1/2017,54,320,320+10=330
1/2/2017,5,110,110+20=130
1/2/2017,51,120,120+23.5=143.5
1/2/2017,54,130,130+10=140
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ngroup, cumcount and mapping i.e

```
x = df.groupby('date')
d = {5: 20, 51: 23.5, 54: 10}
df['new'] = (x.cumcount()+x.ngroup())*10 +df['id'].map(d)+df['value']
```

Output :

```
       date  id  value    new
0  1/1/2017   5    300  320.0
1  1/1/2017  51    300  333.5
2  1/1/2017  54    300  330.0
3  1/2/2017   5    100  130.0
4  1/2/2017  51    100  143.5
5  1/2/2017  54    100  140.0
```

Explanation

```
(x.cumcount()+x.ngroup()
```

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    3
```

```
 (x.cumcount()+x.ngroup())*10 +df['value']
```

```
0    300
1    310
2    320
3    110
4    120
5    130
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
df['adjusted_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: dictionary[x['id']] + x['value'] , axis=1)
```

More verbose:

```
df['adjusted_value'] = [dictionary[i] for i in df['id']]
df['adjusted_value'] = df['adjusted_value'] + df['value']
```